# How to end a PHP session on page close

Tags: php, session

I have several pages inside an AJAX directory. I don't want these pages accessible directly so you cannot just type in the URL of the page within the AJAX directory and access it. I "solved" this by using a PHP session on the page that calls it as follows:
Main page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['download']='ok';
?>
```

and on the ajax page I have this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['download']!=='ok'){
$redirect='/index.php'; //URL of the page where you want to redirect.
header("Location: $redirect");
exit;}
?>
```

The only problem is that if a user goes through the correct process once, the cookie is stored and they can now access the page directly. How do I kill the session once they leave the parent page?

thx

Comment: Why don't you want these pages accessible directly? Genuine Q, I've seen several Q's like this and I'm curious. I mean, you have security on your ajax code so it doesn't matter if a user does, right?

Comment: @James, because my boss is weird about such things. The pages brought in via .load(); are unstlyled and unsightly. One is a form we don't want being submitted unless its viewed through the parent page (in a modal). what do you mean by security on my ajax code? its just a jquery function now...please advise none of the information is critical though more of an aesthetic thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution is to open up each of the files you want to protect from direct URL entry & add the following to the top:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['ajax']) != true) die();?>
```

Now get rid of your redirect script since it's useless now. You don't need to use sessions for this. Every time you request a page, use it's direct URL, just add `?ajax=1` to the end of it.

By adding the `?ajax=1`, PHP will set a key of '`ajax`' to the `$_GET` global variable with the value of `1`. If `?ajax=1` is omitted from the URL then PHP will not set a key of '`ajax`' in `$_GET` and thus when you check if it's set with `isset()` it will return false, thus the script will die and not output anything. Essentially the page will only output data if `?ajax=1` is at the end of the URL.

Someone could still "spoof" the URL and add '`?ajax=1`' themselves, but that is not the default behavior for people or web browsers. If you absolutely need to prevent this then it will be much more complicated, e.g. using templates outside of a publicly available folder. Most other "simple" solutions will have the same "spoofing" potential.

Comment: thx for the help. Here's where I'm at with Sessions - I know they can be spoofed, it works ok. There's no appended url to copy and paste in but once you hit the page you can circumvent the main page and directly access it. With the method above, if you hover over the link it shows the url with ?ajax=1, which can be copied and pasted and circumvent the page. It is the lesser of two evils though, unless there is a way to hide the appended url when you hover over the link?

Comment: I just ended up using yours and adding the ?ajax=1 to the url in the jquery funciton. Not ideal but works better than the rest of what I've done so far. Thx again Klinky

Comment: This is pretty much impossible with sessions unless you get complicated with them. You have no control over where the user visits after the session is set. HTTP is stateless, you do not know when the user is done visiting the parent page on the server side. The only thing I could think of that would be a "simple" session solution would be to have 'download' key timeout after 1 minute, or have it track what pages the user was on and where they went to next. This is much more complicated and may not even provide a better solution.

Comment: yeah i tried making the session timeout, but after how long? I mean they could go to the page, read it all and then try and load content...so a minute? two? five? ten? seems like the above is the best solution, I just changed the die to header(location:main.php'). thx man

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: I know this thread is very old but here goes anyway. You seem to be using jQuery `.load(url)`.  You seem to read `url` from the link's href when clicked. But you don't have to append `?ajax=1` to the HTML href of the links.  You can instead just append that to `url` inside the javascript, after the href  has been read.  Then the link hover issue will at least disappear.

Answer (score 2):

why use session ?

if i understood what you want:

```
<?php /// Is ajax request var ?

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])=="xmlhttprequest") {

           // do your ajax code


    }    else {
           // redirect user to index.php since we do not allow direct script access, unless its ajax called
            $redirect='/index.php'; //URL of the page where you want to redirect.
            header("Location: $redirect");

        exit();
    }
    } ?>
```

Comment: ok, i think this is the best solution, but I don't fully understand it. please be patient with me! so this code goes on the page that is to be included via jQuery's .load command correct? what goes where you have // do your ajax code, is that the html/php content of the page to be loaded? also, Ive noticed I dont always get the "X-CONTENT TYPE: xmlhttprequest" in firebug when I select the link to load these pages, its kind of inconsistent even though they are all using jquery's .load

Comment: It's important to note that as `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is an HTTP header it can still be spoofed by attacker.

Comment: so how do you prevent people from directly accessing files inside certain directories while  still letting the site use them??

Comment: See my revised answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126642/how-to-end-a-php-session-on-page-close/4126844#4126844

Comment: @pygorex the point here is not absolute security, but to prevent people from loading a page outside of an ajax call. Putting the code above at the top of each of your files in the AJAX folder should be enough to prevent that. Yes someone could spoof it via custom headers, but that isn't a big deal unless this information is sensitive. If it is sensitive then Dirty Bird Design needs to use a more complex authentication setup with username/password, which would allow unique identification of each user and then limit or kick people out that don't belong.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way to accomplish this with a 100% certainty - the problem is, both AJAX and regular web browser calls to your web site are using the same underlying protocol: HTTP. If the integrity and security of your site depends on keeping HTTP clients from requesting a specific URL then your design is wrong.

> so how do you prevent people from directly accessing files inside certain directories while still letting the site use them??

Create a controller file. Send all AJAX requests to this controller.

ajax-control.php

```
<?php
 $is_ajax = true;
 include "ajaxincludes/test.php";
 // ... use the ajax classes/functions ...
```

ajaxincludes/test.php

```
<?php
 if (!isset($is_ajax) || !$is_ajax)) {
  exit("Hey you're not AJAX!");
 }
 // ... continue with internal ajax logic ...
```

If clients try to access the file directly at http://mysite/ajaxincludes/test.php they'll get the error message. Accessing http://mysite/ajax-control.php will include the desired file.

Comment: this is still a little above my head. There are 6 files inside the AJAX directory that could be called depending on the link you click. 1. How would I differentiate them in the ajax-control.php 2. where you have // ... continue with internal ajax logic ... that would simply be the code in the page to be brought in with ajax correct? would I include all the doctype, body and html tags? I apologize, but this is new to me as a designer. thx

Comment: You could add a parameter to the request that the controller script reads and uses to select the specific AJAX script.  However, don't go passing the filename directly or an attacker can convince your controller to load arbitrary files which is a serious security risk.

Comment: I am not sure their setup has an MVC architecture. This solution might require them to redesign their setup, which might not be a bad thing, but may be over their head or may be overly complex for the task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a surefire way to do what you are asking, since HTTP request headers can be faked.  However, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see if the request appears to be coming from another page on your site.

If the rest of the security on your site is good, the failure of this method would not grant the user access to anything they were not already able to access.

Comment: I have tried that but can't seem to get it to work, <?php if {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] !== ('http://www.mydomain.com') {
header('location:http://www.google.com');} else... but to no avail

Comment: The referer, if set, is the entire URL of the previous page; that may help you.  Granted, I'm not 100% sure how referer gets set on ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but maybe you could do something with jQuery's [.unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) and then call a PHP page to `unset()` the session.

Answer (score 0):

Why not (on Ajax page):

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['download']!=='ok'){
    $redirect='/index.php'; //URL of the page where you want to redirect.
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}

// do whatever you want with "access granted" user


// remove the download flag for this session
unset($_SESSION["download"]);
```

Comment: Because if the AJAX is called twice from the same parent page, the 2nd call won't work.